# 403 error on PHP - lighttpd

Tags: php, lighttpd

I have set up the `fastcgi` properly, unhashed it from the `module.conf`,

```
[root@xlh lighttpd]# service lighttpd status Redirecting to
/bin/systemctl status  lighttpd.service lighttpd.service - Lightning
Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements     Loaded: loaded
(/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; disabled)      Active: failed
 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
(code=exited, status=255)     CGroup:
name=systemd:/system/lighttpd.service
```

---

```
[root@xlh lighttpd]# php-cgi -v PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in
/etc/php.ini on line 113 PHP 5.3.18 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Oct 18 2012
07:07:56) Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0,
Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

When I go to `localhost/index.php` it throws a **403 error**.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the permissions on the file you are serving to be readable by the server.

This will set the permissions to be editable by the owner, and readable by everyone: 'chmod 644 index.php'